# Warning: Illegal offset type

Tags: php, html

mi duda es que si puedo hacer algo como esto:

```
$variable = $_POST[$nombre];
```

O hay alguna manera de que el parametro que se pone dentro de $_post no sea un texto predefinido entre comillas simples '', sino un dato que es almacenado por la variable nombre?

Comment: Si, es posible utilizarlo. De hecho hay veces que de utiliza con array_keys para recorrer índices de $_post...

Comment: Si, da el siguiente error: 
Warning: Illegal offset type

Comment: Gracias, he encontrado el error, al ser un una busqueda sql, me faltaba ponerle el nombre de la columna